# What's the mb_substr() equivalent?

Tags: twig

Please take a look at the following line of PHP code:

```
<?php echo mb_substr($logged_text, 0, 12, "utf-8"); ?>
```

How can I write it using Twig?

---

There is a type of filter in Twig named [`slice`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html), but I want a thing that handles `utf-8`

Comment: You've answered your own question; from the page you linked: "The slice filter works as the array_slice PHP function for arrays and mb_substr for strings with a fallback to substr."

Comment: A custom Twig extension can be helpful : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: or https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/u.html